# CheckPoint E80.70 on Windows 10 x64 1703 caused BSOD

Tags: bsod, remote-access, windows-10-v1703

CheckPoint E80.70 has been released (2017-05-14) in order to be compatible with Windows 10 x64 1703.

But as soon as it installed on my 2 different computers, HP EliteBook 850 G4 laptop & unbranded new desktop, I'm facing BSOD (Blue Screen) several times a day.

BSOD has stopped immediately only after uninstalling it.

Any ideas / solutions. 
Thanks!

Comment: contact the support of the tool so that they can fix it. We can't fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Installation using the Basic Remote Access Client option (the 3rd installation option) solved the BSOD completely.
Since then it's working fine, without any further issues.

Enjoy :) 
Harel